# Find the multiplicative inverse of x in a quotient ring.

Tags: ring-theory

This isn't exactly homework but I'm reviewing past papers (without solutions for an exam), and need some help with the following question:

Find the multiplicative inverse of x in the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_2$[x]/ $\equiv_f$$_($$_x$$_)$.

From an earlier part of the question $f(x) = x^3 + x^2 + 1$, and I've shown that f(x) is irreducible in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_2$[x]. I'm not entirely sure that this definition for f(x) carries on to part b of the question (find the multiplicative inverse) but I'm assuming it does.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Since we're quotienting out by f, in the quotient ring, $x^3+x^2=1$, so $x(x^2+x)=1$, giving $x^{-1}=x^2+x$

Comment: Thankyou kindly, I need to do some more arithmetic exercises with polynomial rings and quotients..